# How do I use a reference key on a query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have this two models: Tutorial and Chapter. Chapters have a key reference to the tutorial they belong. Now I'm trying to list all the chapter that belong to a specific Tutorial but I can't get the query to work:

```
class TutView(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        tutKey = self.request.get('tut_key')
        tut = db.Key.from_path('Tutorial', tutKey)
        chaps = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Chapter " +
                            "WHERE __key__ = KEY('Tutorial', :1)", tut)
        self.render('tutView.html', chaps=chaps)
```

When running I get this error:

```
BadArgumentError: Expected an integer id or string name as argument 2; 
received datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Tutorial', u'<bound method 
Tutorial.key of <main.Tutorial object at 0x00.............
```

---

Chapter model:

```
class Chapter(db.Model):
    tutorial = db.ReferenceProperty(Tutorial, collection_name='chapters')
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

Tutorial model:

```
class Tutorial(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    presentation = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

---

update:
i managed to get no errors but i get no results (so, probably it's wrong):

```
chaps = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Chapter " + 
                    "WHERE __key__ = KEY('tutorial', :1)", str(tutKey))
```

update2:
The problem might be on the way i store or retrieve the tutKey. I'm getting the key with the URL... and and that's probably not working... but i don't know other way

Comment: Please post you db.Model Classes.

Comment: Replace `__key__` with `chapters`

Comment: why? Chapter doesn't have any property called 'chapters'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KEY()` GQL function is used to create Keys based on two parameters: The Entity, and the name/id.
If you look at your code, you will see that you are passing it a `db.Key` object as a parameter.
Hence, the error message:

```
Expected an integer id or string name as argument 2; 
received datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Tutorial', ...)
```

Also, you need to test against the `tutorial` property of the `Chapter` entity, and not against its own `__key__`.

I do not work with GQL, I use the Query objects instead. You provide them with the `db.Key` object directly, so I assume this should work:

```
chaps = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Chapter " +
                        "WHERE tutorial = :1", tut)
```

If it doesn't, you can always try:

```
chaps = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Chapter " +
                        "WHERE tutorial = KEY('Tutorial', :1)", tut.id() or tut.name())
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a query to return an entity from key just use:

```
chaps = Tutorial.get(tut).chapters
```

Comment: ?? this just gives me the Tutorial, wich i already know. I need the chapters that have a referenceProperty to this tutorial

Comment: the model Tutorial doesn't have a chapters property.

Comment: but i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chapters'

Comment: That is because get returns no entity make sure your key is valid

Answer (score 0):

start an app locally and run the interactive console:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin/interactive
```

copy and paste the code bellow into the console
You can easily try different things and print out the results

```
from google.appengine.ext import db


class Tutorial(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    presentation = db.TextProperty(required=True)

class Chapter(db.Model):
    tutorial = db.ReferenceProperty(Tutorial)
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)

a = Tutorial(title="First tut", presentation="first")
a.put()

print a
print a.key().id()

b = Chapter(tutorial=a, title="tut2", content="lots of words")
b.put()

print b
print b.key().id()

chap = Chapter.all().filter("tutorial =", a).fetch(1000)

for i in chap:
  print i.tutorial.title
```

Comment: what the hell? I'm doing the same thing but... in the datastore the reference to the in Chapters is 'Tutorial: name=#'  but when i posted this code on the console instead of 'name=' i got 'Tutorial: id=#'

Comment: Hmm? Maybe change the names of the models? (Or start an empty app) It does work and you can at least start from something simple that works @mFontoura